# How can I find the results of a search field using a Filter "EQ" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, sapui5

I have an Input element that acts as a search field. The function below filters the user input against the scope's data after they submit the search.

My question is: How can I locate the results from the filtering? For instance, say a user enters a valid product, but the data shows no history of it--I would like to have a way where I can notify a user (ie: an alert) if the submitted query results in no matches from the data?

```
onFilterProduct : function (oEvent) {
         // build filter array
        var aFilter = [], 
            //get the searchfield Id
            oInput = this.byId("productSearch"),

            oTable = this.getView().byId("idProductsTable"),
            oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items"),

            //get searchfield value
            sQuery = oInput.getValue(),

    if (sQuery) {

            //push matches into aFilter array                
            aFilter.push(new Filter("Product", FilterOperator.EQ, sQuery));

            oBinding.filter(aFilter);
        };
    };
```

I don't know where to find this inside the 'aFilter' array.

Here is an example if it will help
http://jsbin.com/vigeg/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oBinding.getLength()` to get the number of entries in the list binding after applying the filter. In your case 0 would be returned. Another way is to call `oTable.getItems()` after applying the filter and it will return an empty array.